# Upgraded from 12.04 to 13.04: not sure how to locate my past Desktop's folders

Tags: 12.04

I moved on from 12.04 to 13.04, Desktop version, and in so doing I have inadvertently created another user account, under a different name compared to what I had defined in the 12.04 installation some time ago.

I noticed that upon logging in my new 13.04 I could no longer see my past directory structure, as these effectively belong to another user which is not the one I have now.

Is my past user lost? Most of my stuff was on a dropbox folder, but something was on the Desktop. Ubuntu One's BackUp is also failing me but this is a separate issue.

thank you for your patience.
Massimo

Comment: Have you updated or reinstalled Ubuntu? What does `ls -lah /home/` say?

Comment: Fire up you file manager and look in the /home folder, which users homefolders you have.

Comment: Hi, I have updated. Found past structure under /home/my_past_user; Thank you

Comment: @prophecy201 - can you please post that as an answer so massimopinto can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command  `ls -lah /home/` to take a look at your home-folders to find yours.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Radu but it helps to find the "old" home directory.